# Как сделать круглый ProgressBar в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть изображение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется обвернуть картинку индикатором загрузки и менять цвет по мере продвижения индикатора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно свой Control писать

Comment: Ну или поместить на задний фон, за картинку, эллипс и закрашивать его линиями, чем и занимаюсь

Comment: Можно стилизовать прогрессбар. Напишу попозже.

Comment: @VladD Все мои решения пришли в тупик, стилизированный прогрессбар сейчас бы пригодился, спасибо

Comment: @zakihatfild: Сделал.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну что же, давайте напишем стиль для `ProgressBar`'а, ведь в конце-концов вы показываете `ProgressBar`, правильно?

Для начала, нам нужен будет конвертер, превращающий угол в геометрию, описывающую наш круглый прогрессбар.

Вспомним тригонометрию и в путь!

```
class RoundProgressPathConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values?.Contains(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) != false)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        var v = (double)values[0]; // значение слайдера
        var min = (double)values[1]; // минимальное значение
        var max = (double)values[2]; // максимальное

        var ratio = (v - min) / (max - min); // какую долю окружности закрашивать
        var isFull = ratio >= 1; // для случая полной окружности нужна особая обработка
        var angleRadians = 2 * Math.PI * ratio;
        var angleDegrees = 360 * ratio;

        // внешний радиус примем за 1, растянем в XAML'е.
        var outerR = 1;
        // как параметр передадим долю радиуса, которую занимает внутренняя часть
        var innerR =
              System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * outerR;
        // вспомогательные штуки: вектор направления вверх
        var vector1 = new Vector(0, -1);
        // ... и на конечную точку дуги
        var vector2 = new Vector(Math.Sin(angleRadians), -Math.Cos(angleRadians));
        var center = new Point();

        var geo = new StreamGeometry();
        geo.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

        using (var ctx = geo.Open())
        {
            Size outerSize = new Size(outerR, outerR),
                 innerSize = new Size(innerR, innerR);

            if (!isFull)
            {
                Point p1 = center + vector1 * outerR, p2 = center + vector2 * outerR,
                      p3 = center + vector2 * innerR, p4 = center + vector1 * innerR;

                ctx.BeginFigure(p1, isFilled: true, isClosed: true);
                ctx.ArcTo(p2, outerSize, angleDegrees, isLargeArc: angleDegrees > 180,
                    sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked: true,
                    isSmoothJoin: false);
                ctx.LineTo(p3, isStroked: true, isSmoothJoin: false);
                ctx.ArcTo(p4, innerSize, -angleDegrees, isLargeArc: angleDegrees > 180,
                    sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, isStroked: true,
                    isSmoothJoin: false);

                Point diag1 = new Point(-outerR, -outerR),
                      diag2 = new Point(outerR, outerR);
                ctx.BeginFigure(diag1, isFilled: false, isClosed: false);
                ctx.LineTo(diag2, isStroked: false, isSmoothJoin: false);
            }
            else
            {
                Point p1 = center + vector1 * outerR, p2 = center - vector1 * outerR,
                      p3 = center + vector1 * innerR, p4 = center - vector1 * innerR;

                ctx.BeginFigure(p1, isFilled: true, isClosed: true);
                ctx.ArcTo(p2, outerSize, 180, isLargeArc: false,
                    sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked: true,
                    isSmoothJoin: false);
                ctx.ArcTo(p1, outerSize, 180, isLargeArc: false,
                    sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked: true,
                    isSmoothJoin: false);
                ctx.BeginFigure(p3, isFilled: true, isClosed: true);
                ctx.ArcTo(p4, innerSize, 180, isLargeArc: false,
                    sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked: true,
                    isSmoothJoin: false);
                ctx.ArcTo(p3, innerSize, 180, isLargeArc: false,
                    sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked: true,
                    isSmoothJoin: false);
            }
        }

        geo.Freeze();
        return geo;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                                CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Окей, конвертер есть, теперь нам нужен сам стиль. Он несложен, единственный интересный пункт — состояние `Indeterminate`.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundProgressBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}"
       xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:RoundProgressPathConverter x:Key="Conv"/>
        <!-- нам понадобится пара констант -->
        <!-- доля рабиуса для внутренней части -->
        <sys:Double x:Key="RelativeThickness">0.75</sys:Double>
        <!-- просто 0 -->
        <sys:Double x:Key="Zero">0.0</sys:Double>
        <!-- просто 1 -->
        <sys:Double x:Key="One">1.0</sys:Double>
        <!-- какой процент рисовать для неопределённого состояния -->
        <sys:Double x:Key="IndeterminatePart">0.25</sys:Double>
        <!-- обычно прогресс по умолчанию зелёный -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Progress" Color="#FF06B025"/>
        <!-- стандартный фон -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
        <!-- стандартный цвет границы -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Progress}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
                    <!-- в неопределённом состоянии запускаем вращающуюся анимацию -->
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Animation"
                                        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <!-- это фон, красим его в цвет фона-->
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stretch="Uniform"
                          Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv}"
                                          ConverterParameter="{StaticResource RelativeThickness}">
                                <!-- val=1, min=0, max=1 даёт полный круг -->
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource One}"/>
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource Zero}"/>
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource One}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Uniform" Name="Indicator">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv}"
                                          ConverterParameter="{StaticResource RelativeThickness}">
                                <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <!-- это анимировнная штука, будет показываться в неопределённом состоянии -->
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Uniform" Name="Animation"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv}"
                                          ConverterParameter="{StaticResource RelativeThickness}">
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource IndeterminatePart}"/>
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource Zero}"/>
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource One}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Path.Data>
                        <!-- положим пустое вращение, чтобы к нему цеплялась анимация -->
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- в случае неопределённого состояния уберём нормальный индикатор и покажем анимацию -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Animation" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Отлично, нам теперь нужно поменять цвета на кастомные, и можно запускать.

Обыкновенный:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="SliderBg.png" Stretch="None"/>
    <ProgressBar Value="0.7" Maximum="1"  Height="100" Width="100" 
                 Style="{DynamicResource RoundProgressBarStyle}"
                 Foreground="#FFED1C24" Background="#FFEBB249"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: обыкновенный прогресс бар]

То же, с `IsIndeterminate="True"`:

[image: неопределённый прогресс бар]

(он вращается).

Comment: Style="{DynamicResource RoundProgressBarStyle}" выдаёт: не удалось разрешить ресурс "RoundProgressBarStyle"

Comment: @zakihatfild: Ну, а вы стиль куда положили? Или может быть вы его назвали не так? Должно видеть.

Comment: я создал настраиваемый элемент управления WPF, стиль положил в Generic.xaml, а конвертер в класс который оно создало

Comment: @zakihatfild: «Настраиваемый элемент управления» — это custom control? А почему бы не сделать просто так, как я написал: не делать отдельный контрол, а использовать стиль для ProgressBar'а? В Generic.xaml кладутся стили для custom control'ов. Положите стиль в `Application.Resources`.

Comment: а конвертер в обычный класс?

Comment: @zakihatfild: Разумеется. Так, как написано в ответе, без изменений.

Comment: Имя "RoundProgressPathConverter" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:RecMe". Выдаёт в разметке стиля

Comment: @zakihatfild: А в каком пространстве имён у вас `RoundProgressPathConverter`?

Comment: в пространстве имён RecMe

Comment: @zakihatfild: Перепроверьте, потому что сообщение об ошибке говорит, что .там его нету. Или вы находитесь в другой сборке, в эта у вас не подключена?

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать геометрию WPF.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp1.PartialCircle"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"    
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480" >

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Path StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
            Stroke="Orange"
            StrokeThickness="5">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure
                        StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint}" >
                        <ArcSegment
                            x:Name="Whatup"
                            Point="{Binding EndPoint}"
                            Size="{Binding Size}"
                            RotationAngle="0"
                            IsLargeArc="{Binding IsLarge}"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                            />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C# код:

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;



    public partial class PartialCircle : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double radius = 100;

        private double percentage = 13;

        public PartialCircle()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Задает процент
        /// </summary>
        public double Percentage
        {
            get
            {
                return this.percentage;
            }

            set
            {
                this.percentage = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();

                this.OnPropertyChanged("Angle");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsLarge");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("EndPoint");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Радиус закругления
        /// </summary>
        public double Radius
        {
            get
            {
                return this.radius;
            }

            set
            {
                this.radius = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();

                this.OnPropertyChanged("StartPoint");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Center");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Size");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("EndPoint");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Координаты центра окружности
        /// </summary>
        public Point Center
        {
            get
            {
                return new Point(this.Width/2, this.Height/2);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the starting point of the path
        /// </summary>
        public Point StartPoint
        {
            get
            {
                return new Point(this.Center.X, this.Center.Y - this.radius);                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Размеры сегмента
        /// </summary>
        public Size Size
        {
            get
            {
                return new Size(this.radius, this.radius);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Угол, на котором необходимо остановиться
        /// </summary>
        public double Angle
        {
            get
            {
                return 359.99 * this.Percentage / 100;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Корректировка при переходе через 180 градусов
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsLarge
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.Percentage > 50);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вычисление конечной точки
        /// </summary>
        public Point EndPoint
        {
            get
            {
                // Pi correction
                var angle = this.Angle - 90;
                return this.CalculateCircleCoordinates(this.Center, this.radius, angle);
            }
        }

        private Point CalculateCircleCoordinates(Point center, double radius, double angle)
        {
            var radians = (angle * Math.PI) / 180;
            return new Point(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(radians), center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(radians));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использование в приложении:

```
<PhoneApp1:PartialCircle Width="300" Height="300" Percentage="100" Radius="150"/>
```

Изменяем Persentage (%). А картинку можно уже класть поверх или под низ нашего элемента.

**UPDATE 1:** Вариант использования

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
                    {
                        this.RoundProgressBar.Percentage = i; 
                    }));
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Хорошо, я создал UserControl, вставил исходник.<PhoneApp1:PartialCircle Width="300" Height="300" Percentage="100" Radius="150"/> нужно вставить в разметку главного окна, а куда разметку xaml UserControl писать?

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду... вы случаем не создали `UserControl` для `WinForm`? Для WPF есть свой "Пользовательский элемент управления WPF"

Comment: разобрался вставил всё куда надо в коде C#
 использую UserControl.Percentage = ++progress;
 но ничего не отображается

Comment: имя дайте своему UserControl? и через него обращайтесь

Comment: progress++; RoundProgressBar.Percentage = progress;

Не работает

Comment: Добавил пример использования

Comment: Не работает. Ещё вопрос когда мы добавили элемент в главное окно, Percentage = 100, т.е. должен быть сразу виден оранжевый круг ( Stroke="Orange" ), а его - нет

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7BB171EC7A61C76F!14443&authkey=!AJL9kmIAbHGQGFc&ithint=file%2czip  Вот мой рабочий вариант

Answer (score 0):

Советую сделать две картинки - с индикатором (image1) и без (image2). Поместить image1 поверх image2. Изначально сделать image1 прозрачным или вообще не показывать. По мере изменения прогресса показывать сектор image1. Думаю, что это решение лучше закрашивания линиями, и надеюсь, что WPF позволяет реализовать такое решение.

Comment: Просто я не могу найти как закрасить сектор, не то чтобы выводить

Comment: @zakihatfild, к сожалению, стандартными средствами мой вариант не реализовать. Простите за ложный путь.