# Изогнутый Progress Bar c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

Ребят, подскажите как сделать полукруглый прогресс бар? С обычным вообще не возникает проблем. Находил только больно уж сложные, круглые примеры [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520400/10105

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Просто тут и не будет, придется помудрить с геометрией.

Ну что ж, давайте создадим `UserControl`, я назвал его `MyProgress`.

Рисовать будем с помощью `Path`. Контрол будет состоять из двух `Path` - закрашенного и незакрашенного (закрашенного другим цветом). Для упрощения расчетов я взял эллипс с радиусами 100 и центром в точке (100,100).

Нам нужно нарисовать 2 луча из центра и дугу:

```
<Path Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                <LineSegment Point="0,100"/>
                <ArcSegment Point="170.71,29.29"
                            Size="100,100"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Точку я рассчитал для варианта 75% заполненности, вот что уже получается:
[image: 1]

Теперь из этого сектора нужно вырезать круг меньшего диаметра, сделаем это с помощью `CombinedGeometry` в режиме `Exclude`:

```
<Path Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                        <LineSegment Point="0,100"/>
                        <ArcSegment Point="170.71,29.29"
                                    Size="100,100"
                                    SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="80" RadiusY="80"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

[image: 2]

Теперь аналогично рисуем вторую часть другим цветом:

```
<Path Fill="Cyan" Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                        <LineSegment Point="200,100"/>
                        <ArcSegment Point="170.71,29.29"
                                    Size="100,100"
                                    SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="80" RadiusY="80"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

[image: 3]

С разметкой пока всё, останется только привязать координаты рассчитанной точки в `ArcSegment`.

Займемся кодом контрола:

Свойство зависимости `Value`:

```
public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double),
                    typeof(MyProgress), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged));
```

Вспомогательное свойство зависимости с координатами точки дуги:

```
protected static DependencyProperty AuxiliaryPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AuxiliaryPoint",
                    typeof(Point), typeof(MyProgress));
```

Стандартные оболочки для этих свойств:

```
public double Value
{
    get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
}

protected Point AuxiliaryPoint
{
    get => (Point)GetValue(AuxiliaryPointProperty);
    set => SetValue(AuxiliaryPointProperty, value);
}
```

Ну и, наконец, метод, который будет пересчитывать координаты точки при смене `Value`:

```
static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myProgress = (MyProgress)d;
    var value = (double)e.NewValue;
    var angle = Math.PI * value / 100;
    var x = 100 - 100 * Math.Cos(angle);
    var y = 100 - 100 * Math.Sin(angle);
    myProgress.AuxiliaryPoint = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Теперь в разметке привяжемся к рассчитанной точке:

```
Point="{Binding ElementName=myProgress, Path=AuxiliaryPoint}"
```

Это нужно сделать для обоих `ArcSegment`

В разметке я дал имя контролу для упрощения кода привязки:

```
<UserControl ...
             Name="myProgress">
```

Всё. Это уже минимально рабочий прогрессбар, который можно добавить в окно:

```
<local:MyProgress x:Name="Progress1" Value="0"/>
```

Выглядит так:

[image: 4]

Имейте ввиду, чтобы сделать этот контрол более-менее универсальным, вам потребуется его еще доработать, например, вынести в свойства зависимости цвета дуг и фона, минимальное и максимальное значение прогрессбара, диаметр внешнего и внутреннего круга и т.д.

Привожу код контрола полностью, `MyProgress.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfProgress.MyProgress"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Name="myProgress">
    <Grid>
        <Path Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                                <LineSegment Point="0,100"/>
                                <ArcSegment Point="{Binding ElementName=myProgress, Path=AuxiliaryPoint}"
                                            Size="100,100" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="80" RadiusY="80"/>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Cyan" Stroke="Black">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                                <LineSegment Point="200,100"/>
                                <ArcSegment Point="{Binding ElementName=myProgress, Path=AuxiliaryPoint}"
                                            Size="100,100" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="80" RadiusY="80"/>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`MyProgress.xaml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfProgress
{
    public partial class MyProgress : UserControl
    {
        public MyProgress()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double),
                            typeof(MyProgress), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged));
        protected static DependencyProperty AuxiliaryPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AuxiliaryPoint",
                            typeof(Point), typeof(MyProgress));

        static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var myProgress = (MyProgress)d;
            var value = (double)e.NewValue;
            var angle = Math.PI * value / 100;
            var x = 100 - 100 * Math.Cos(angle);
            var y = 100 - 100 * Math.Sin(angle);
            myProgress.AuxiliaryPoint = new Point(x, y);
        }

        public double Value
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        protected Point AuxiliaryPoint
        {
            get => (Point)GetValue(AuxiliaryPointProperty);
            set => SetValue(AuxiliaryPointProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Раз `UserControl` несемантично, я сделал стиль (благодаря помощи @VladD) для `ProgressBar`. Потом решил добавить возможность редактирования внутреннего радиуса из разметки. Но аттачед проперти, меняющее поведение контрола, тоже несемантично, поэтому в итоге остановился на `Custom Control`, наследованном от `ProgressBar`.

Идея используется та же, что описана в решении выше, но теперь контрол доработан полностью (наверное), поэтому разметка усложнилась из-за кучи привязок, а также из-за реализованного режима `Indeterminate`.

Для тех, кто хочет создать такой контрол - добавьте в проект `Add - New Item - Custom Control WPF`, я назвал его `SemicircleProgressBar`, код самого контрола предельно прост - добавлено одно свойство зависимости:

```
public class SemicircleProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    static SemicircleProgressBar()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SemicircleProgressBar),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SemicircleProgressBar)));
    }

    public static DependencyProperty CuttingFactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CuttingFactor), typeof(double),
            typeof(SemicircleProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.8));

    public double CuttingFactor
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(CuttingFactorProperty);
        set => SetValue(CuttingFactorProperty, value);
    }
}
```

В появившемся файле `Generic.xaml` в папке `Themes` в корне проекта разметим стиль нового контрола:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfProgress"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SemicircleProgressBar}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <local:ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter x:Key="ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter"/>
            <local:RadiusToSizeConverter x:Key="RadiusToSizeConverter"/>
            <sys:Double x:Key="OneDouble">1.0</sys:Double>
            <sys:Double x:Key="ZeroDouble">0.0</sys:Double>
            <sys:Double x:Key="QuarterDouble">0.25</sys:Double>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SPB.Progress" Color="#FF06B025"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SPB.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SPB.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SPB.Progress}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SPB.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SPB.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SemicircleProgressBar}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Animation"
                                                         From="0" To="135"
                                                         Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Animation"
                                                         From="135" To="0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                        <PathGeometry>
                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,1">
                                                <ArcSegment Size="1,1" Point="2,1" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                                            </PathFigure>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                        <EllipseGeometry Center="1,1"
                                                         RadiusX="{Binding CuttingFactor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                         RadiusY="{Binding CuttingFactor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                </CombinedGeometry>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <Path Name="Indicator" Stretch="Uniform"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,1">
                                        <ArcSegment Size="1,1" SweepDirection="Clockwise">
                                            <ArcSegment.Point>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource OneDouble}"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </ArcSegment.Point>
                                        </ArcSegment>
                                        <LineSegment>
                                            <LineSegment.Point>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="CuttingFactor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </LineSegment.Point>
                                        </LineSegment>
                                        <ArcSegment Size="{Binding Path=CuttingFactor,
                                                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                                   Converter={StaticResource RadiusToSizeConverter}}">
                                            <ArcSegment.Point>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="CuttingFactor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </ArcSegment.Point>
                                        </ArcSegment>
                                        <LineSegment Point="0,1"/>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <LineSegment Point="2,1" IsStroked="False"/>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <Path Name="Animation" Stretch="Uniform"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Visibility="Collapsed" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,1">
                                        <ArcSegment Size="1,1" SweepDirection="Clockwise">
                                            <ArcSegment.Point>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource QuarterDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource ZeroDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource OneDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource OneDouble}"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </ArcSegment.Point>
                                        </ArcSegment>
                                        <LineSegment>
                                            <LineSegment.Point>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource QuarterDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource ZeroDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource OneDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="CuttingFactor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </LineSegment.Point>
                                        </LineSegment>
                                        <ArcSegment Size="{Binding Path=CuttingFactor,
                                                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                                   Converter={StaticResource RadiusToSizeConverter}}">
                                            <ArcSegment.Point>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource ZeroDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource ZeroDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource OneDouble}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="CuttingFactor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </ArcSegment.Point>
                                        </ArcSegment>
                                        <LineSegment Point="0,1"/>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <LineSegment Point="2,1" IsStroked="False"/>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </Path.Data>
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Animation" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Конвертеры.
`ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter`:

```
class ValueToAuxiliaryPointConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Contains(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        var v = (double)values[0];
        var min = (double)values[1];
        var max = (double)values[2];
        var r = (double)values[3];
        var ratio = (v - min) / (max - min);
        var angle = Math.PI * ratio;
        var x = 1 - r * Math.Cos(angle);
        var y = 1 - r * Math.Sin(angle);
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

`RadiusToSizeConverter`:

```
class RadiusToSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var r = (double)value;
        return new Size(r, r);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Код для демонстрации:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                 Value="75" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Height="100" Width="200"/>

    <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                 IsIndeterminate="True"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Height="100" Width="200"/>

    <local:SemicircleProgressBar x:Name="SemiCpb1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                 Value="75" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
                                 CuttingFactor="0.8"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 Height="100" Width="200"/>

    <local:SemicircleProgressBar x:Name="SemiCpb2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                 IsIndeterminate="True"
                                 CuttingFactor="0.8"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 Height="100" Width="200"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Demo]

Использована информация из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520886/218063)

Comment: [Ошибки](http://prntscr.com/g3wa6y) Все так же сделал =\

Comment: У вас студия древняя, неплохо бы обновить. А пока замените `get => ...` на `get { return ... }` и `set => ...` на `set { ... }`

Comment: @Андрей, а что за формулы стоят за расчетом угла и координат X и Y?

Comment: @sp7, расчет угла это просто доля от развернутого угла пи. Здесь захардкожен диапазон от 0 до 100, поэтому делю на 100. А координаты - обычные синусы и косинусы для точек на окружности, с учётом смещения 100 от начала координат до центра. Ну и минусы перед синусом и косинусом из-за того, что у нас начало отсчёта угла смещено на полоборота и направление отсчёта обратно (по часовой стрелке)

Comment: Юзерконтрол немного несемантично, лучше оформить как стиль для ProgressBar'а.

Comment: Подскажите за одно как из кода отрисовать этот бар на форме другого окна. Для меня wpf какой то страшный зверь =))

Comment: @ИгорьАга, зачем вам это понадобилось? Лучше уж добавить контрол в разметку и из кода управлять его видимостью

Comment: @VladD, а можете помочь: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63368/room-for--and-vladd

Comment: @Андрей: Отписался в чате.

Comment: Thanks man. Works like a charm. I actually joined this community so I can upvote your solution :)

Comment: @mrid, welcome! I am glad if it was useful for you.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the curved edges more sharp/smoother? I've tried `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` and `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"` but the border edges are still not smooth

Comment: @mrid, this is complicated: https://habr.com/post/216833/