# WPF плавная отрисовка круга

Tags: c#, wpf

Продолжаю разбираться с анимацией, и на этот раз не могу справиться с задачей плавной отрисовки круга, т.е. как будто человек его рисует ручкой.

Понял, что вмешаться в процесс отрисовки через Ellipse не получится, потому пошел в сторону Path и ArcSegment.

Как я понял, просто нарисовать круг через ArcSegment не получится, придется рисовать два полукруга. Но как управлять углом отрисовки? Ведь анимацию плавной отрисовки необходимо именно на этот параметр устанавливать.

Может есть какие-то другие способы нарисовать "бублик"?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701535/218063 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520886/218063

Comment: В принципе, контрол из ответа VladD делает то что вам нужно, достаточно анимировать Value от Minimum до Maximum

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно одного ArcSegment.

Данные, общие для каждого шага - радиус окружности (два раза в Size), и центр окружности,  направление заполнения (например, CCW) и  RotationAngle

На каждом шаге из центра, радиуса и угла рассчитывается конечная точка - аргумент Point. Кроме того, для углов более 180 градусов нужно изменить соотв. аргумент IsLargeArc