# Кастомный ProgresBar WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Помогите сделать кастомный ProgressBar прочитал [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701412/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-progress-bar-c-wpf/701535) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520400/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9-progressbar-%D0%B2-wpf) пост
дело в том, что мне нужен ProgressBar не совсем правильной(круглой) формы

это xaml будущего ProgressBar

```
  <Path
     Data="M449.23438,366.5625 L467.47438,376.5425 C444.66025,422.18786 431.48069,469.97556 427.84939,519.88642 L406.61504,519.88642 C411.03924,464.08389 425.14082,412.9256 449.23438,366.5625 z"
     Stretch="Fill"
     Stroke="White" />
```

ProgressBar 0%

[image]

ProgressBar 80%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эта фигура построена по какой-то формуле?

Comment: нет просто руками отрисовал инструментом "Pen"

Comment: Ну тогда просто делайте 100 (или сколько вам надо их) семплов и просто меняйте их в зависимости от значения

Comment: Не совсем понял о чем Вы говорите, можете пояснить?

Comment: Подготовьте 100 готовых изображений вашего прогрессбара, для 0% заполненности, для 1% и т.д. И просто меняйте их. А может вам вообще будет достаточно 20-25 изображений

Comment: Либо, если вам не нравится такой подход — вам придется придумать формулу, которая строила бы вашу фигуру, в самом простом случае это будет какая-то кривая второго порядка — эллипс/парабола/гипербола

Answer (score 2):

Сделал костыльный вариант, для моих целей подходит

xaml

```
<UserControl Name="PrBar">
<Grid>
  <Path
        Width="59.419"
        Height="154.047"
        Margin="36.531,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Data="M248.0625,203.3125 C226.50766,246.55013 213.87989,293.72255 209.65417,344.59833 L189.64323,344.65545 C193.8575,290.18792 207.25521,238.96503 231.5968,191.60875 z"
        Stretch="Fill"
        Stroke="White" >
        <Path.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
                        <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=PrBar, Path=AnglePRM}" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
                        <TranslateTransform />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <GradientStop Offset="{Binding ElementName=PrBar, Path=GradientPRM}" Color="OrangeRed" />
                <GradientStop Offset="{Binding ElementName=PrBar, Path=GradientPRM}" Color="Transparent" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
    </Path>    
  </Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

cs

```
public partial class ProgBar : UserControl
{
    public ProgBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ValuePRMProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ValuePRM", typeof(double),
                         typeof(ProgBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnValuePRMChanged));

    protected static DependencyProperty AnglePRMProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AnglePRM",
                        typeof(double), typeof(ProgBar));
    protected static DependencyProperty GradientPRMProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GradientPRM",
                     typeof(double), typeof(ProgBar));

    static void OnValuePRMChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myProgress = (ProgBar)d;
        var value = (double)e.NewValue;
        if (value >= 100)
            value = 100;
        if (value <= 0)
            value = 0;
        myProgress.GradientPRM = value * 0.01;
        myProgress.AnglePRM = myProgress.GradientPRM * 13 - 172;
    }

    public double ValuePRM
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ValuePRMProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValuePRMProperty, value);
    }

    protected double AnglePRM
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(AnglePRMProperty);
        set => SetValue(AnglePRMProperty, value);
    }

    protected double GradientPRM
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(GradientPRMProperty);
        set => SetValue(GradientPRMProperty, value);
    }
  }
}
```

Управляя заливкой, получаю эффект заполнения, AnglePRM - отвечает за правильный угол заливки