# Элемент управления для визуализации обратного отсчёта с анимацией дуги окружности

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, инспекция-кода, countdown

Я реализовал элемент управления для визуализации обратного отсчёта с анимацией дуги, который выглядит вот так:

[image: Элемент управления, отображающий обратный отсчёт.]

[инспекция-кода](/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Код рабочий, но требуется обратная по поводу качества реализации данного элемента управления.

---

Заметки по реализации:

- Для визуализации дуги я создал класс `Arc`, унаследовавшись от `Shape` (код основан на этом [посте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16669648/1548895)).
- Я создал элемент управления `Countdown` (наследует `UserControl`). Для установки таймаута я добавил свойтсво зависимости (dependency property) `Seconds`. I'm using binding `Content="{Binding Seconds}"` to display seconds. Анимация выполняется в code behind

  ```
  Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds));
  ```

  потому что я не уверен, возможно ли это сделать в XAML без написания специального конвертера. Я полагаю, что написание здесь своего конвертера ради одной строчки кода здесь не оправдано.
- Для масштабирования элемента управления, его содержимое обёртнуто в элемент управления `Viewbox`.
- Я анимации секунд я использую `DispatcherTimer`, ничего особенного. Нет ли способа это сделать лучше?

---

### Код

`Arc.cs`

```
public class Arc : Shape
{
    public Point Center
    {
        get => (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CenterProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Center.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(Arc), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    // Start angle in degrees
    public double StartAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    // End angle in degrees
    public double EndAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EndAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EndAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(90.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double Radius
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(RadiusProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public bool SmallAngle
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(SmallAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(SmallAngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SmallAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SmallAngle", typeof(bool), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    static Arc() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            double startAngleRadians = StartAngle * Math.PI / 180;
            double endAngleRadians = EndAngle * Math.PI / 180;

            double a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? startAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : startAngleRadians;
            double a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? endAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : endAngleRadians;

            if (a1 < a0)
                a1 += Math.PI * 2;

            SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
            bool large;

            if (SmallAngle)
            {
                large = false;
                double t = a1;
                d = (a1 - a0) > Math.PI ? SweepDirection.Counterclockwise : SweepDirection.Clockwise;
            }
            else
                large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);

            Point p0 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * Radius;
            Point p1 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * Radius;

            List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>
            {
                new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(Radius, Radius), 0.0, large, d, true)
            };

            List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>
            {
                new PathFigure(p0, segments, true)
                {
                    IsClosed = false
                }
            };

            return new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
        }
    }
}
```

`Countdown.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.Countdown"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Name="Animation"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arc"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="EndAngle"
                        From="-90"
                        To="270" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Border Background="#222" Margin="5" CornerRadius="50">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="{Binding Seconds}" FontSize="50" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" />
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="sec" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, -20, 0, 0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <local:Arc
                x:Name="Arc"
                Center="50, 50"
                StartAngle="-90"
                EndAngle="-90"
                Stroke="#45d3be"
                StrokeThickness="5"
                Radius="45" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

`Countdown.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class Countdown : UserControl
{
    public int Seconds
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SecondsProperty);
        set => SetValue(SecondsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Seconds), typeof(int), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

    public Countdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds));
        if (Seconds > 0)
        {
            _timer.Start();
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Seconds--;
        if (Seconds == 0) _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Элемент управления помещается на окно с помощью подобного кода

```
<local:Countdown Width="300" Height="300" Seconds="25" />
```

---

Такой же вопрос на [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197197/119568).

Comment: Первое, что бросается в глаза - я бы заменил таймер асинхронным кодом - и тогда сам таймер и калбек для него не понадобится.

Comment: @tym32167 А можно демострацию этого, пожалуйста? А то я не улавливаю так.

Comment: Добавил пример. Также мне не нравится логика в геттере `DefiningGeometry` - я бы содержимое вынес в отдельную функцию, и кешировал бы результат, чтобы по 100500 раз не вычислять одно и то же.

Comment: @tym32167 Так это же [tag:инспекция-кода]. А можете также это добавить в ваш ответ? Там значения во время анимации разные, я не совсем представляю что же именно там следует кешировать.

Comment: Как вариант, можно взять круглый прогрессбар отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520886/218063 внутренний TextBlock привязать к Value прогрессбара, а само значение или изменять по таймеру как у вас, или через штатную анимацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После обратной связи на [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197197/119568), внёс такие измения:

- Анимация выполняется в code behind для того, чтобы автоматически обновлять и дугу, и обратный отсчёт. Это гарантирует отстутствие рассинхронизации таймера и анимации дуги.
- Созданы отдельные Dependency-свойства для длительности обратного отсчёта `Duration` и оставшегося времени `SecondsRemaining` для универсальных и понятных binding'и.
- Добавлены методы `Start`, `Stop` и событие `Elapsed`.
- Исправлено отображение обратного отсчёт из-за отсутствия округления в более высокую сторону.
- Различные мелкие рефакторинги вроде использования оператора `nameof` и т.д.

---

### Результат

`Arc.cs`

```
public class Arc : Shape
{
    public Point Center
    {
        get => (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CenterProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Center), typeof(Point), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double StartAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StartAngle), typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double EndAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(EndAngle), typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(90.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double Radius
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(RadiusProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Radius), typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public bool SmallAngle
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(SmallAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(SmallAngleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SmallAngle), typeof(bool), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    static Arc() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            double startAngleRadians = StartAngle * Math.PI / 180;
            double endAngleRadians = EndAngle * Math.PI / 180;

            double a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? startAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : startAngleRadians;
            double a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? endAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : endAngleRadians;

            if (a1 < a0)
                a1 += Math.PI * 2;

            SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
            bool large;

            if (SmallAngle)
            {
                large = false;
                d = (a1 - a0) > Math.PI ? SweepDirection.Counterclockwise : SweepDirection.Clockwise;
            }
            else
                large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);

            Point p0 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * Radius;
            Point p1 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * Radius;

            List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>
            {
                new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(Radius, Radius), 0.0, large, d, true)
            };

            List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>
            {
                new PathFigure(p0, segments, true)
                {
                    IsClosed = false
                }
            };

            return new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
        }
    }
}
```

`Countdown.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.Countdown"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450" Loaded="Countdown_Loaded">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Border Background="#222" Margin="5" CornerRadius="50">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="{Binding SecondsRemaining}" FontSize="50" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" />
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="sec" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, -15, 0, 0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <uc:Arc
                x:Name="Arc"
                Center="50, 50"
                StartAngle="-90"
                EndAngle="-90"
                Stroke="#45d3be"
                StrokeThickness="5"
                Radius="45" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

`Countdown.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class Countdown : UserControl
{
    public Duration Duration
    {
        get => (Duration)GetValue(DurationProperty);
        set => SetValue(DurationProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DurationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Duration), typeof(Duration), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(new Duration()));

    public int SecondsRemaining
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SecondsRemainingProperty);
        set => SetValue(SecondsRemainingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsRemainingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SecondsRemaining), typeof(int), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public event EventHandler Elapsed;

    private readonly Storyboard _storyboard = new Storyboard();

    public Countdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(-90, 270, Duration);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Arc);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(nameof(Arc.EndAngle)));
        _storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Countdown_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
            Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();

        _storyboard.CurrentTimeInvalidated += Storyboard_CurrentTimeInvalidated;
        _storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;

        _storyboard.Begin();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _storyboard.CurrentTimeInvalidated -= Storyboard_CurrentTimeInvalidated;
        _storyboard.Completed -= Storyboard_Completed;

        _storyboard.Stop();
    }

    private void Storyboard_CurrentTimeInvalidated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClockGroup cg = (ClockGroup)sender;
        if (cg.CurrentTime == null) return;
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = cg.CurrentTime.Value;
        SecondsRemaining = (int)Math.Ceiling((Duration.TimeSpan - elapsedTime).TotalSeconds);
    }

    private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
            Elapsed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
<local:Countdown Width="300" Height="300" Duration="0:0:15" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример как избавиться от таймера

```
public partial class Countdown : UserControl
{
    public int Seconds
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SecondsProperty);
        set => SetValue(SecondsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Seconds), typeof(int), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(0));      

    public Countdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private async void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds));

        while(Seconds > 0)
        {
            var delayTask =  Task.Delay(1000);
            Seconds--;
            await delayTask;
        }       
    }   
}
```

Чем этот вариант отличается от таймера:

1) Обработка исключений - тут в случае исключения код после цикла (если бы он был) не выполнялся бы. Ну и, асинхронный вариант можно обернуть в try-catch.

2) Новая итерация цикла не будет выполнена, пока предыдущая не завершится. То есть, если цикл будет выполняться 5 секунд, то следующая итерация наступит только через 5 секунд. Таймер же, по идее, отрабатывать должен через строгие интервалы времени, хотя насчет DispatcherTimer я не уверен.

По поводу выноса метода, я имел ввиду что то вроде

```
protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get
    {
        var ret = CalcDefiningGeometry(StartAngle, EndAngle, SmallAngle, Radius, Center);
        return ret;
    }
}

private static Geometry CalcDefiningGeometry(double startAngle, double endAngle, bool smallAngle, double radius, Point center)
{
    double startAngleRadians = startAngle * Math.PI / 180;
    double endAngleRadians = endAngle * Math.PI / 180;

    double a0 = startAngle < 0 ? startAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : startAngleRadians;
    double a1 = endAngle < 0 ? endAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : endAngleRadians;

    if (a1 < a0)
        a1 += Math.PI * 2;

    SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
    bool large;

    if (smallAngle)
    {
        large = false;
        double t = a1;
        d = (a1 - a0) > Math.PI ? SweepDirection.Counterclockwise : SweepDirection.Clockwise;
    }
    else
        large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);

    Point p0 = center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * radius;
    Point p1 = center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * radius;

    List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>
        {
            new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(radius, radius), 0.0, large, d, true)
        };

    List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>
        {
            new PathFigure(p0, segments, true)
            {
                IsClosed = false
            }
        };

    return new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
}
```

Как это кешировть и нужно лит это кешировать - это уже надо на месте разбираться. Выносить в метод предпочтительней, так как после этого легче будет менять код - будь то добавление кеширования или вынос логики в отдельный класс

Comment: Мне в целом импонирует этот подход. А есть ли в нём помимо небольшого сокращения объёма ещё какие-либо преимущства?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov обновил ответ

Comment: Насчёт 2, DispatcherTimer сработает *абсолютно* также

Comment: Топик по теме таймера: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696486/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну это логично, он жеж не может запускать свои дела параллельно, но в одном потоке. Разве что если попробовать запустить асинхронный код внутри обработчика DispatcherTimer - то тогда какая-то гонка может иметь место.