# Создание выпадающего котрола поверх остальных

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Необходимо сделать кнопку для настройки "Фильтра", при нажатии выпадает контрол с настройками фильтра. Пробовал сделать это с помощью `ZIndex` и `Expander`, но решение не самое красивое.

Вот набросок того, что должно быть(настройки фильтра должны быть поверх остального контента)

[image: набросок выпадающего элемента управления]

Comment: ContextMenu посмотрите для начала, если не подойдет – придется делать Popup

Comment: @АндрейNOP, посмотрел про Popup. Если я правильно понимаю, то это лучшее решение, если не смотреть на количество кода?

Comment: Самое правильное – это точно

Comment: @UporotayaPanda Вы попробуйте использовать `Popup`, сделайте максимально хорошо, если получится. И если получилось, то можете задать вопрос с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода] и вам дадут обратную связь по поводу качества вашей реализации. К примеру, вот [мой недавний вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846356/220571) такого формата.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, хорошо, на днях залью ответ, нужно задавать новый вопрос или можно обновить этот?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda Мне кажется, что лучше создать новый вопрос и, возможно стоит добавить ваше решение также сюда ответом. Также добавьте в вопросы ссылки друг на друга, так как они связаны друг с другом. Почему новый вопрос? Потому что во-первых поменялась специфика: здесь вы спрашиваете "как сделать", а там будете спрашивать "я вот сделал, достаточно ли это хорошо", во-вторых, ваш новый вопрос может получить больше внимания, чем этот. Также наличие ссылок друг на друга обеспечит внимание двум вопросам.